# Twin breaker allowance

Tags: wiring, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

I plan to use a tandem(AKA duplex, slimline, twin, half-height, half-inch, double or wafer breakers) circuit breaker for kitchen.

The 20 Amp Tandem Single Pole Type QT Circuit Breaker ( [here is the link to it](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Siemens-20-Amp-Tandem-Single-Pole-Type-QT-Circuit-Breaker-Q2020U/100016494) ) will feed 2 GFCI outlets for countertop.

Now, I ask if is OK this setup. Inspector says that is OK as long the breaker is on dual phases.

Here is her answer: "You can use the slimline product, but it must be on dual phases.They each need a neutral."

What does it means? I couldn't find some info about twin breakers for dual or single phase.

Answer (score 4):

### Lost in translation

The inspector is giving you the standard warning not to use double-stuff breakers on MWBC (shared neutral) circuits. Sounds like you fully understand that requirement... and they aren't telling you anything new

Comment: what do you mean by "you are way ahead of them..."?

Comment: I agree for tandem 2 hots 2 neutrals no way to do a MWBC with tandems.+

Answer (score 0):

If your inspector says you need the breaker to be on two phases, that probably means you have a Multi-Wire Branch Circuit (MWBC).  That means you need a proper two-slot breaker, not typical a double-stuff -- those only can grab one phase.  You can use a so-called "quad" breaker, where the internal ones (and possibly the outer pair as well) are proper common-trip two pole breakers, suitable for MBWCs.  See @Harper 's answer here (and the linked answers) for the full details with pictures: [Why are tandem breakers on shared neutral (MWBC) problematic?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/160851/why-are-tandem-breakers-on-shared-neutral-mwbc-problematic)

Comment: I do not want to use MWBC. Just keep it simple. Each circuit on its own cable.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure why your inspector is insisting they be on separate phases then.  I suppose your options are to either argue with your inspector or simply wire it *as if* it were a MWBC, with a two-pole breaker at the panel, but with separate neutral wires.  Either way, if you read through the linked answer (and the ones it links to) that will give you all the info you need about dual vs single phase tandem breakers, so you can have a more informed discussion with your inspector.

Comment: If she said they each need a neutral, probably wasn't talking about MWBC.  If they were on a separate phase, you could use the same neutral.  Very conflicting advice.  If each breaker has a neutral running with it's hot, you should be fine.

Comment: @JPhi the twin breaker operate two different circuits 12-2 cable on each connection

Comment: As long as each cable has a white and a black, you're ok.  The confusing parts come in when you want to run two circuits and you have a cable with white, black, and red.  The white will be "shared" and that has to be done correctly.

Comment: Yeah, @cadobe, with your edit that the inspector is requiring separate neutrals but a two pole breaker, that doesn't make a lot of sense -- typically you only need the two pole breaker if you're sharing neutral.  You might need to clarify with them exactly why they're requiring that.

Comment: Perhaps your inspector meant that each GFCI needs its own neutral, but you could share neutral upstream of the GFCIs with a two pole breaker?

Comment: @JPhi1618, yes the cables I plan to use are 12-2 romex which has a black, white and neutral. Black to screw connector into twin(first connector) white to the neutral and copper to the ground which actually is bounded to the neutral, this serving one dedicated circuit. Same story for second circuit going into second screw connector on twin.

Comment: @cadobe You mean black, white and **ground** (not “neutral”)